# Can zinc (over)supplementation cause hypocalcemia?

Tags: side-effects, supplement, calcium, zinc

From [Wikipedia's article on hypocalcemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocalcaemia) ([version dated 27 Nov 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hypocalcaemia&oldid=870906209)):

> Causes: 
>   ...
>   Excessive dietary zinc, as with supplementation (causes rapid hypocalcemia)

I googled but found no studies corroborating this statement. Is there any evidence in support of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There seems to be no evidence that zinc supplements would cause hypocalcemia in humans.**

According to the study [Effect of zinc supplements on the intestinal absorption of calcium (PubMed, 1987)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3584729), calcium and zinc may inhibit each other's absorption:

> the high zinc intake decreased the intestinal absorption of calcium
>   during a low calcium intake but not during a normal calcium intake

But:

[Office of Dietary Supplements by NIH.gov](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Zinc-Consumer/) does not mention hypocalcemia as a possible side effect of zinc supplements.

[Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/drug-interactions/zinc-sulfate,zinc.html) does not mention any interaction between zinc and calcium supplements.

Also, the mentioned claim from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocalcaemia) lacks any reference.

In *rats,* zinc supplements can cause acute hypocalcemia ([PubMed, 1981](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7334451)), but I'm not aware of any association of this study with humans.